# Dividing values in a GROUP BY query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I am trying to divide numHospitalizations by numCases to get percent hospitalized and numDeaths by numCases to get percent death. There is a lot of repeat health districts so I thought it would be best to group by healthDistrict but I keep getting:

> not a GROUP BY expression.

```
SELECT healthDistrict AS HEALTH_DISTRICT
    , (numHospitalizations / numCases) AS PERCENTHOSP
    , (numDeaths / numCases) AS PERCENTDEATH
FROM CovidReport
GROUP BY UPPER(healthDistrict);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using SQL Server? Are you using some query designer in SSMS or some other UI tool to design the query? "Not a group by expression" is not a SQL Server error message, maybe you could post the whole message? Also if your columns are `int` or similar, SQL Server uses integer math, e.g. `10/7 = 1` and `7/10 = 0`. So you'll also need to perform a conversion to decimal somewhere in each expression.

Comment: Also, please show some sample data and desired results, so we know what you want. From the query I can't tell what answer you want from `'my district', 200, 126, 12` and `'my district', 170, 112, 14`. Do you want the average over the sum, over the max, something else?

Answer (score 2):

You need to form aggregates of all columns that you are not grouping on (and prevent division by zero).

```
SELECT
  UPPER(healthDistrict) AS HEALTH_DISTRICT,
  CASE WHEN SUM(numCases) > 0 THEN SUM(numHospitalizations) * 1.0 / SUM(numCases) ELSE 0 END AS PERCENTHOSP,
  CASE WHEN SUM(numCases) > 0 THEN SUM(numDeaths) * 1.0 / SUM(numCases) ELSE 0 END AS PERCENTDEATH
FROM
  SomethingSlightlyLessMorbid
GROUP BY
  UPPER(healthDistrict);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is what you're after, but [an MCVE would be really useful](https://sqlblog.org/ask).

```
;WITH agg AS
(
  SELECT 
    UPPER(healthDistrict) AS HEALTH_DISTRICT, 
    Hosp   = SUM(numHospitalizations)*1.0,
    Cases  = NULLIF(SUM(numCases)*1.0,0),
    Deaths = SUM(numDeaths)*1.0
  FROM dbo.SomethingSlightlyLessMorbid
  GROUP BY UPPER(healthDistrict)
)
SELECT HEALTH_DISTRICT,
       PERCENTHOSP  = CONVERT(decimal(8,2), (Hosp   / Cases)), 
       PERCENTDEATH = CONVERT(decimal(8,2), (Deaths / Cases))
FROM agg;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a8b1329a2d5f79744a0c8542b2279554)

Comment: ...I'm wondering, why the CTE?

Comment: (also this will throw division by zero)

Comment: @Tomalak `why the CTE?` so I don't have to repeat `SUM(numCases)` four times. `division by zero` possibly, though I expect a row making it into this specific data set with 0 cases is unlikely. Fixed, without multiple lengthy `CASE` expressions, too. :-) If 0 is possible I'll let the OP decide if they want 0 or NULL.

Comment: I don't think SQL server will re-actually *calculate* the sum four times, though. ("It probably won't happen" is a weak defense against a lingering division-by-zero bug.)

Comment: Yeap, that's better :)

Comment: I know SQL Server shouldn't actually re-calculate the SUMs, but I also don't know that it's guaranteed not to. Anyway, many people think it will, and then we have to have this exact conversation, and it just seems redundant, so I try to avoid it when I can. A CTE where it's only mentioned once _also_ doesn't guarantee it won't be calculated multiple times. But it sure looks cleaner to me. YMMV.

Comment: Yeah, it's subjective. I don't mind the repetition (plus I have full trust in the people who write query optimizers), and I prefer the less complex syntax in exchange.

Comment: @Tomalak I think "less complex syntax" is subjective, too. I find repetition unnecessarily complex and after so many years on Stack Overflow separating things logically into a CTE often helps people grasp the concepts better.

Comment: LOL  @ "Miracle, TX" :D

Comment: @Tomalak That should be two laughs if you've seen [The Leftovers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Leftovers_(TV_series)). And a must-watch if you haven't.

Comment: No I haven't, I'll give it a watch.